# Rails bootstrap index page grid layout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, blogs

I am stuck with a very unusual behaviour of bootstrap. I am working with rails in which I have to build an index page containing blogs in tile system. It is working fine for larger screen but when we reduce the size it is creating extra space. Can't figure out why this space is being created. Any help would be appreciated.

[the code for grid layout for index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0pR1.png)

[when experimenting with screen sizes and larger data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5TH0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I can see on the image, I'd say the content of your upper left div is bigger than the content of your upper right div.
I've had simular issues with images of different sizes.

Try placing you content inside of rows, this will prevent the huge whitespace.

Example :

```
<div class='container'>
 <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-xs-6'></div>
   <div class='col-xs-6'></div>
 </div>
 <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-xs-6'></div>
   <div class='col-xs-6'></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but in context of rails when implementing it through  <% @blogs.each do |blog| %> I am getting this error , you can see in images given.